# ffmpeg delay in creating HLS segment files

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using `ffmpeg` to produce segment files to be used for HLS. This is being done on a live video stream, and I'm piping H264 frames to `ffmpeg` as I receive them. The frame rate is about 10fps and I want each segment to be 1 second of video. This works, except that there's about a 10 second delay between the time I start sending frames to `ffmpeg` and the time the first segment file is created. At the time I see the first segment file created, I've already written about 120 frames to `ffmpeg`. This is the command I'm running:

```
ffmpeg -report -r 10.3 -i pipe:0 -c:v h264 -flags +cgop -g 10 -hls_time 1 out.m3u8
```

I'm a novice user of `ffmpeg` so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong. Is there some way to cause it to create segment files as soon as it has the frames it needs?

The `-report` output is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HqKG8sA3fLk_DwKUv323ybNHA6QKRhJm/view?usp=sharing

Update: I was able to get the latency down by using `-probesize` with a small value (I tried 5000). I now see the first file after sending about 40 frames.

Comment: Share full report after adding -report and removing -hide_banner

Comment: I updated the question with the report. I shared it as a link to a file since it's fairly large. Thanks.